# Xamarin Restful Services (get put post delete)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

We need URL while we are creating a connection to SQL
but how can i create URL? I could not find anything.

Comment: you need to write a webservice that brokers the connection between the client and your db.  There are numerous articles and samples on writing RESTful services for different platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a web service connected to your database. Then, you will be able to interact with this web service (which will access database) from your Xamarin application using URLs, and HTTP get, put post and delete. As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) said, creating a RESTful API is a good idea. You'll find plenty articles about that, the one I used to learn basics is there :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api